# Map right Alt to Ctrl key

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, setxkbmap

I use Linux Mint Mate 17, which is based on Ubuntu 14.04,
and I want to map my right <kbd>Alt</kbd> to act as a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key
(since I can reach it with my right thumb, which is more comfortable). 
How can I do that?

I tried to search online. 
However, most guides are based on using `Xmodmap`,
which seems to be deprecated. 
Some others use `xkb`, but I eventually gave up configuring it. 
One of the attempts was to add something like

```
key <ALTGR> { [ Control_L ] };
```

to xkb_symbols "pc105" section of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`,
but it didn't work. 
In fact, I understand neither why I should use specifically this file
(there are a lot of them in symbols directory, and I've found include "pc" line only in macintosh_vndr/apple file), nor where I should learn the right name of the key – RALT or ALTGR is just my suggestion, nor what the section name pc105 means.

After some more searching, I found out that the following command does what  I want:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:ralt_rctrl
```

However, it obviously works only for the current session. I tried to add it to my `.profile`, but it didn't help. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Mate, based on GNOME 2

Comment: I'm not familiar with _mate_  but here's how to permanently add `xkb` options to [_gnome3_ via `dconf` editor](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250020) so it should be similiar...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. `dconf-editor` is available for MATE too and I used it exactly like in your post (now xkb-options value is `['ctrl:ralt_rctrl']`), but the mapping didn't appear. Do you know any ways to debug this?

Comment: No, as I said I'm not familiar with _mate_... If it matters, the option works fine in _gnome3_ as I just tried it. If you're using a `systemd` setup you can always check `journalctl -b` (as a regular user) and see if you get any error about that option in `input-sources`... Otherwise try `~/.xsession-errors` maybe you find something there.

Comment: GNU Linux Debian (stretch) has /etc/default/keyboard for XKBOPTIONS setup.